# CSS :before tag over letter

Tags: css

So i have this "container:before" to create an epic effect to the background, BUT the problem is that the letter is behind it and not over it,
i tried using z-index: 2 and position: absolute; the lette got on top, but NOT in CENTER.

```html
<style>
<?php
 $color = "51, 204, 51";
?>

@font-face {
    font-family:"mixoly";
    src: url("mixolydian titling ul.ttf") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}
#container {
  font-family:'mixoly', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(<?php echo $color; ?>, 0.80);
  color: white;
}
#container:before { 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%; 
  background-color: rgb(<?php echo $color; ?>);
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(25deg);
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}
</style>

<div id="container">
 <font size="40px">
  <b>
   A
  </b>
 </font>
</div>
```

Comment: `<font size="40px">` Seriously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give `z-index: -1` to the `:before`.

Like this:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "mixoly";
  src: url("mixolydian titling ul.ttf")
  /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}
#container {
  font-family: 'mixoly', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(51, 204, 51, 0.80);
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}
#container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  background-color: rgb(51, 204, 51);
  top: 0;
  z-index:-1;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(25deg);
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   A
</div>
```

Comment: I don't wanna insult you, but please have a look at http://w3fools.com, before even uttering that filthy website's name!

Comment: W3Schools still has issues but they have at least worked on the primary concern developers had. For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience. However, it would be a mistake to continue your education without learning from more reputable sources, so when you're ready to level up, move on.

Comment: okay, just went to mozilla : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font and its obsolete ! thank you :)